# How to leave implementation to later in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

In Scala there is the `???` operator which lets the compiler continue without complaining about something not being implemented, if you are testing another part of the program.

Does OCaml have an equivalent operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `failwith "not implemented"` or `raise` any exception you want. These functions, both defined in [`Pervasives`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html), return `'a`, which the compiler will infer to be anything you want it to be.